# Does anybody recognize this connector?

Tags: connector, solar-cell, identification

Does anybody recognize this connector? This is Power terminal used on Solar Inverter. Rated for 150A/35V.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Well, it's clearly a terminal block.

I think [this](http://www.comestero.com/uploads/fck/file/new%20product/MORSETTI%20LXX_MAGGIO2010_INGLESE.pdf) is what you are looking for. And I think [this](http://catalog.weidmueller.com/catalog/Start.do?localeId=de_DE&ObjectID=1047600000) is the link to the product from the manufacturer.

Sorry, that's all the information I could find out about it.

Comment: @WinsonHou Thanks for the feedback. Do you mind selecting my answer as best if it satisfied you? Thank you.